# Making parent aria-label read first, and then child content

Tags: html, accessibility

I have code where I have `listitem` instead of a `list`. The content that is being read is as follows:

`Item 2, group list mylist 2 items`.

I would like it to be read like:

`mylist 2 items, Item 2`.

Basically, I want the parent list aria-label to be read first, and then the child element.

Here's the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/81sc9dum/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, looks like you can do this if you introduce the value for the element that you want to be read later (aria-label) on the event itself.

So if it's on focus, you actually add the aria-label on focus, and then it would read the parent first, and then the child.